Spring Boot: DELETE request returns 204 but doesn't delete the record from the database
I'm working on a Spring Boot application and trying to implement a DELETE endpoint to remove a record from the database. The API responds with 204 No Content, and my application logs indicate that the record is successfully deleted. However, the record still exists in the database when I query it directly.
Here is my setup:
Controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/appliances")
public class ApplianceController {

    private final ApplianceRepository applianceRepository;

    public ApplianceController(ApplianceRepository applianceRepository) {
        this.applianceRepository = applianceRepository;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAppliance(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (!applianceRepository.existsById(id)) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        applianceRepository.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}

Repository:
@Repository
public interface ApplianceRepository extends JpaRepository<Appliance, Long> {
}

Entity:
@Entity
public class Appliance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private boolean isOn;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", nullable = false)
    private Room room;

    // Getters and setters
}


Try removing the @Transactional the deleteById is already transactional (and ideally the call should be in a service not in a controller but that is anohter discussion.

you can use the @OnDelete annotation or configure cascading
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "room_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Room room;

or you can use cascading delete configuration in your Room entity
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "room", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Appliance> appliances;


Why should the room be removed if we remove an appliance? Next to that the relation doesn't prevent the removal of the appliance.

sorry i create my reply to delete room only or the seconde on for deleting all

update only your controller method to ensure changes are flushed like this: @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity deleteAppliance(@PathVariable Long id) {
if (!applianceRepository.existsById(id)) {
return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
applianceRepository.deleteById(id);
applianceRepository.flush(); // Ensure deletion is flushed to the database
return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}

Tried your suggestion and nothing helped so far, I seriously don't know what is wrong with it, the other deleteApartment and deleteRoom method work without any problems, but this one is seriously annoying me... Also there is no "delete" log in the api

flushing doesn't commit, so flushing doesn't change a thing (a common mistake made by people). Is this really your delete method (although as stated that really should be in a service marked with @Transactional and not in your controller).
